# How to go about hand painted textures?

Tags: texturing

I have been going through the arduous task of switching back and forth between clip studio and blender when trying to make clothing textures and it feels very inefficient and difficult to visualize shading when i'm plainly looking at a UV map on my 2D software. I waste a ridiculous amount of time going back and forth and not being able to see my model in real time really makes it hard to paint properly.

In an ideal world i would have wanted to be able to load up my model on the software to paint on it directly. Blender's texturing tools leave much to be desired and i can't separate my drawings into layers nor have any of the customized brushes i use on clip studio. How do i go about this? I just want to hand-paint stylized cloth textures directly on my model with actually good painting tools. Is there no software that can save me the hassle? I just want an idea of where to go before paying for software that may or may not have what i need.

Comment: Texture Paint tools are limited even though some people do amazing things with them, but anyway you have some addons that improve the texture paint in Blender, some allow to work with layers for example

Comment: Blender does not come with the selection of brushes 2D artists are used to using, and so it is a problem that has a) been tackled by many artists who have developed customized brush sets, b) likely to change in future versions of Blender.  So, hang in there, and go to Blender Market or Gumroad and do a search for brushes.  There are even many free brush packs out there.    A second point is that if you do a lot of this work, set up a  file with a good work space for painting, with the texture paint, UV, and shader windows ready to go.  You will be surprised at the results you can get.